# Loop through table names to search for data

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to search for an entry in a table that may be contained in a list of tables.

For example, I have 3 tables named table1, table2, and table3. Each table contains the same fields : id, name, vehicle. Just say I wanted to find a name that exists in 2 of the tables, how would I go about doing it? The amount of tables is dynamic but I can already get them via a query.

Code to get the table names

```
$retrievequery = "SELECT table_name 
                  FROM information_schema.tables  
                  WHERE table_schema = 'bargebooking' 
                  AND table_name NOT LIKE 'slots%'  
                  AND table_name NOT LIKE 'accounts%';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$retrievequery);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $row[] = $data[0];
}
```

This code stores the table names into an array

Code to search through the tables for a name

```
for($i=0;$i<count($row);$i++)
{
    $curr_table = $row[$i];
    $searchquery = "SELECT * FROM `$curr_table` where name='second'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$searchquery);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['id'];
    }
}
```

This is my attempt. So far if i remove the where clause, it will print out all the ids, but only for one table (the first one).

In case you didn't understand, I want to find data that may exist in multiple tables and list them out. 
I hope I can get some help with this.

Comment: If you have three identically structured tables, where the only difference is a digit in the table name, then you're structuring your database badly.... have __one__ table, with an additional `tid` number column, and everything will be so much easier

Comment: Union the results of all 3 tables together in a subquery and then select from the inline view.  though I agree with Mark, I question table design alot here.  `Select * from (Select * from table1 union all select * from table2 union all select * from table3) subqry where col='desiredvalue'`

Comment: Schemas are subject to more than just design standards you know ...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? sql server and mysql are not the same thing.

Comment: Step through the code in the debugger, and look at the query that you are executing for the table that you expect to see results but do not.   The reason will probably be obvious then.

Comment: I agree with the previous commentators regarding the table design.  If you have control over this and the database design is not yet set in stone, I'd consider revising it.  If you do not feel confident in your database design skills or are unsure in this area, get the help of a competent data architect.  Subpar database designs (along with poor data structuring overall) is responsible for a lot of subpar application designs.

Comment: You're right I guess. I'll redesign the table and let you guys know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 subqueries to tell whether the value of the column is in the other 2 tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM `table1`
WHERE `column_t1` IN (
    SELECT `column_t2`
    FROM `table2`
) AND IN (
    SELECT `column_t3`
    FROM `table3`
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

This statement is overriding the $row variable you are looping

Answer (score 0):

With all three tables having the same definition, I'd union all the tables together in your SQL and assign a table id to each. Then apply my search to the result.

Should be easy enough to build string dynamically from the table definitions. using this method it will also tell you which table it was found in if that helps.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   SELECT 1 as tid, * FROM table1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 as tid, * FROM table2
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 as tid, * FROM table3
        )   A
WHERE   keyField = @searchCriterial
```

Any problems then feel free to ask. Always happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change $row name for second query result:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($row);$i++)
{
$curr_table = $row[$i];
$searchquery = "SELECT * FROM `$curr_table` where name='second'";
$name_result = mysqli_query($conn,$searchquery);
while($name_row = mysqli_fetch_array($name_result))
{
    echo $name_row['id'];
}
}
```